# Login in SSMS is successful, but fail to connect from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

I use the `sa` user to login in SSMS, and it succeeds. But when I try to connect my C# application, I get an error.I read it from the https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-access-database.html

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'user 'sa' login fails.'
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.button1_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs
> [External Code]

I try to modify the password and set the server's property and its security is SQL Server and Windows authority node. I add the integrity=true, but it is not what I want.

Here is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  

  string connetionString;
    SqlConnection cnn;

    connetionString = @"Data Source=SK-20200925OWFS;Initial Catalog=youu;User ID=sa;Password=l2345678";

    cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    cnn.Open();

        MessageBox.Show("Connection Open");
        cnn.Close();
        
        
    }
```

Here `youu` is my database.

So how to connect to SQL Server so I can modify the database?
I edit the question,because I add the simi-colon in the password.After i modify, it still doesn't work.
[i can login into the ssms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNkGv.png)

Comment: Just a guess, but did you try it without the trailing semi-colon (`Password=l2345678"`)? Connection strings are never fun

Comment: And seriously, DON'T use your SA password anywhere!

Comment: I celebrate too early,it still doesn't work,headache

Answer (score 0):

Can you try tnsping with that server in the command prompt so it can generate the datasource for you

`tnsping SK-20200925OWFS 1433`

Also, if you're using sa then your datasource ought to be `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

The connectionstring settings should be as follows.

```
 connectionString="Data Source=IP;Initial Catalog=yourdatabasename;User ID=username;Password=password;
```

if you use Local,use Dot(.) or server name instead of IP.

```
 connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=yourdatabasename;User ID=username;Password=password;
```